# rendering a file in React using send_file from Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have a flask route which when hit downloads a specific file:

```
@bp.route("/file-data/<int:file_data_id>", methods=["GET"])
def download_service_file(file_data_id):
    file_download = download_service_file_data(file_data_id)
    return file_download
```

**download_service_file_data**

```
def download_service_file_data(service_file_data_id):
    file_to_download = db_session.query(ServiceFile).filter(ServiceFile.id == service_file_data_id).first()

    return send_file(BytesIO(file_to_download.file_data), attachment_filename=file_to_download.file_label)
```

This is fine, but I would also like to give users the option to just view the file instead of auto-downloading. Does the `send_file` function have the ability to just return the file for a client-side render (preferably in a new tab type of functionality)? Or am I not approaching this right? Any advice would be great. My Client is using React

Comment: What's the type of file you're sending?

Comment: @code it can vary from a pdf to an image

Comment: Usually files won't automatically download unless you specify it so, or you send a mime (file) type that the browser can't read. Where does `BytesIO` come from?